# Timelock update of a smart contract

Tags: program

Is there a standard way to time lock the update of a smart contract or do i have to deploy my own time lock program ? At the moment, i didn't find any information about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With just the upgradeable program loader protocol, there's no way to natively time lock the update of a smart contract. If you want to time lock the update, you'll need to use some other protocol.

For example, the spl-governance program provides for various "waiting" and "cool off" periods in between voting and execution to provide a pseudo-time lock. You can find its docs at https://governance-docs.vercel.app/

There are likely other multisig / DAO programs that give similar functionality.